# Token unknown error in update Trigger

Tags: sql, database, firebird, database-trigger

Here's the update trigger I'm trying to create for a view. It's pretty clear what I'm trying to achieve:

```
SET TERM !! ;
CREATE TRIGGER SST_Insert FOR SpaceSpaceTypes
BEFORE INSERT AS
DECLARE VARIABLE NEW_TYPE_ID;
BEGIN
NEW_TYPE_ID=(SELECT MAX(type_id) FROM SpaceTypes WHERE type_name=NEW.type_name);
INSERT INTO Space values (NEW.address,NEW.company_id,NEW.area,NEW_TYPE_ID);
END!!
SET TERM ; !!
```

I've tried different combos of `!!`'s and `;`'s. I tried dropping a variable. It didn't help. The error for the query above is:
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000

> Dynamic SQL Error
>   -SQL error code = -104
>   -Token unknown - line 3, column 29
>   -;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
DECLARE VARIABLE NEW_TYPE_ID;
```

You haven't specified the type of `NEW_TYPE_ID`, so the statement is incomplete and the semi-colon is unexpected at that position, which causes a *token unknown* error.

The syntax of [`DECLARE VARIABLE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-declare-variable) is:

```
DECLARE [VARIABLE] <varname>
  {<datatype> | <domain> | TYPE OF {<domain> | COLUMN <rel.col>}
    [NOT NULL]  [CHARACTER SET <charset>] [COLLATE <collation>]
    [{DEFAULT | = } <initvalue>];
```

So at minimum you need to use:

```
DECLARE VARIABLE NEW_TYPE_ID INTEGER;
```

Or more advanced:

```
DECLARE VARIABLE NEW_TYPE_ID TYPE OF COLUMN SpaceTypes.type_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option was to leave it as

```
   SET TERM !! ;
    CREATE TRIGGER SST_Insert FOR SpaceSpaceTypes
    BEFORE INSERT AS
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Space values (NEW.address,NEW.company_id,NEW.area,(SELECT        MAX(type_id) FROM SpaceTypes WHERE type_name=NEW.type_name));
END!!
SET TERM ; !!
```